# Can SQL Server's MERGE statement update its merge_search_condition?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I use MERGE for Upsert implementation.
This code might be executed from two different application instances concurrently.
The code:

```sql
MERGE foo as TARGET
USING (SELECT
    @Field1 as [field1],
    @Field2 as [field2],
    @SuperId as [super_id]) as SOURCE
ON TARGET.super_id = SOURCE.super_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    TARGET.[field1] = SOURCE.[field1],
    TARGET.[field2] = SOURCE.[field2]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (
    [field1],
    [field2],
    [super_id])
VALUES (
    SOURCE.[field1],
    SOURCE.[field2],
    SOURCE.[super_id])
OUTPUT
    inserted.common_id;
```

Can it somehow update the `super_id` field? Because that's exactly what I have. There was super_id `1` at the time of August, 23rd. And on September, 12th there was `2`.
I suspect that one machine was mergin on id = 1, and the second one on id = 2. Something went horribly wrong and id got replaced, because there's no rows with super_id = 1.

No other code accesses this table to somehow address the `super_id` field. One other way is for somebody to manually set the `super_id` field by their own hands. That is being investigated.

Comment: INSERT, yes.  UPDATE, no.  Not in this statement.  If there is no other code that touches the table then the value was manually updated.

Comment: That is very interesting indeed. You know, I can't start pointing fingers without evaluating my code first :)
I did not consider MERGE as a source of the bug because it seems absurd, but after looking at the MERGE bug list...you can't be too sure.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's fair.  It is riddled with problems.  So yeah, I'll qualify my comment above by saying "No, not as designed"...

Comment: `MERGE` needs locking hints to ensure concurrency. You should use `MERGE foo as TARGET WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)...` See also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Or better yet, stay away from MERGE...